# MATLAB slider to adjust brightness

Tags: matlab, image-processing, uislider, matlab-guide, brightness

I have an image displayed in an axes and I would like to use a slider to adjust the contrast.

As I am new to matlab I am not too sure how to achieve this so I would appreciate your help.

Thanks a lot

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what is the brightness of a binary image could you specify please? Thanks!

Comment: @Benoit_11 Well it doesn't have to be a binary image...it could be the full RGB one. By brightness I mean contrast ! I m sorry, it was my mistake :) thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the image processing toolbox you can use the [imtool](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/images/adjusting-image-contrast-using-the-adjust-contrast-tool.html) but if you dont you should be able to replicate the effect by altering the `CLim` value of the axes.

Changing the range should alter the contrast and changing the offset the brightness.

Comment: How would I express that in the slider's callback function? Thanks

Comment: You need to get the handle of the axes and update the property based on the slider value